# How can i use Youtube 360º videos in my App React?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube, sensors, virtual-reality

How can i use youtube videos that are in 360º in my React application? i know to get embed code...

I can insert and see them by dragging the screen, **however** my intention is to make it work when I rotate the mobile device or look around with the virtual reality glasses, on youtube it works but when I am using the IFRAME inside my application it it does not allow me to make the movements, just drag the screen.

how do i make it work? in 'Mozilla Developer Edition' it warns me that:

`My Iframe code:`

```
<iframe
src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/YG77CR48VRI'
title="YouTube video player"
frameBorder="0"
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
allowFullScreen
className="vr-video-player"
></iframe>
```

`Console warning:`
`"Using motion sensor is deprecated" "Use of orientation sensor is deprecated."`

I've been searching for 5 days for a solution to this, even here I didn't find it.